# uploading a file from chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to let the user choose and upload a file from the chrome extension popup. But, as soon as the file-chooser dialog opens the popup loses focus and closes immediately. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138567/1937345), the workaround seems to be that I can move the dialog opening logic to the background-page, which is not affected by loss of focus.

I have tried the answer, but the file-chooser does not appear at all. It is weird that `fileChooser.click()` event does actually occur (I was able to verify it by creating a click listener for `fileChooser`). Below is a simplified version just to focus on the problem.

**popup.html**

```
<button id="uploadCSV">Upload CSV</button>
```

**popup.js**

```
$('#uploadCSV').click(function() {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({ action: 'browseAndUpload' });
});
```

**background.js**

```
var fileChooser = document.createElement('input');
fileChooser.type = 'file';
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  if (msg.action === 'browseAndUpload') {
    fileChooser.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same issue, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: relevant 8 years old bug still open https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292701 (it's Firefox specific but I don't think it matters a lot).

Answer (score 0):

**Popup.js**

```
var file = document.getElementById('#file')[0].files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        "uploadFile": true,
        blob: reader.result,
        file: { name: file.name }
    }, x => { })
};
reader.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
};
```

**Background.js**

```
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','),
    mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]),
    n = bstr.length,
    u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}
function uploadFile(msg) {
    var file = msg.file;
    let nfile = dataURLtoFile(msg.blob, file.name)
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('cvFile', nfile);
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "endpoint",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
        "data": formData
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (!0) {
        case 'uploadFile' in msg: uploadFile(msg); break;
    }
})
```