# Can Chrome content and background scripts share access to blob: URLs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

I'm creating a `getUserMedia` stream in a Chrome extension content script, and I'd like to pass it to the background script.

You can't pass non-JSON'able data between them, so my strategy is to pass instead the generated blob URL to the stream.

Content script:

```
function get_stream() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: 1}).then(stream => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'got_stream', params: {stream_url: URL.createObjectURL(stream)}});
    });
```

Background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(data) {
    switch (data.action) {
        case 'got_stream': got_stream(data.params); break;
    }
});

function got_stream(params) {
    let vid = document.createElement('video');
    alert(params.stream_url); //blob:http://...
    vid.src = params.stream_url; //error - file not found
}
```

This is fine... until I try to apply it to a generated `<video />` element, at which point the console says the file is not found.

I assume it's because the background and content scripts are in sandboxed environments.

Is there any way around this without having to do something nuclear like transfer the stream literally via WebRTC or something?

Comment: Blobs can be shared yes, Tampermonkey uses this mechanism for its Instant injection mode. Maybe it works for the media only if it is finished. MDN says createObjectURL is deprecated for MediaStream and suggests srcObject property of the media element. There's no media element in this case, though...

Comment: Yeah that's my problem. Basically I just need to share a stream from content to background but I'm hitting a brick wall with every idea. This is necessitated because if you try and create cam/mic streams from background you get [this bug](https://crbug.com/160337). So only the content script can create cam/mic streams. But I need the background to have access to it for other reasons. Urgh...

Comment: You can do sendMessage it with tracks array not stream!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out this is an origins issue.

The content script runs in the context of the present webpage, whereas the background script runs in the context of the extension.

Blob URLs are grouped by origin, so, in the same way you can't ordinarily AJAX from one domain to another, two domains also can't share blob URLs.

This is solved by running the content script not in the current webpage (so not specified in the manifest under `content_scripts`) but in a new tab or pop-up.

Background:

```
window.open('content-page.html');
```

Content page:

```
<script src='content-script.js'></script>
```

Then, any blob URL generated by content-script.js will be readable to the background, as they are now both running in the context of the extension, i.e. a shared origin.

[EDIT]

If you don't like the idea of a pop-up window (after all, on Mac these are rendered as full tabs), you could instead inject an `iframe` into the current tab and run your content script from there.

To do this, call a content script from your manifest:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content-script-curr-tab.js"]
    }]
}
```

Then in that:

```
let ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
ifr.setAttribute('allow', 'microphone; camera'); //necessary for cross-origin frames that request permissions
ifr.style.display = 'none';
ifr.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('page-to-inject-into-iframe.html');
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

Note `chrome.runtime.getURL()` - that's the key to hosting and running a page in the context of the extension not the webpage.

Then, finally, in `page-to-inject-into-iframe.html`:

```
<script src='script-to-inject-into-iframe.js'></script>
```

Then do your thing in there!

Comment: Any chance you could make an example extension of this and put it on github?

Comment: You can see how I did by installing a Chrome extension called govidigo. Find out where Chrome installs it on your device, then you can see all the code in there.

Comment: No longer works createObjectURL is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

blob urls are likely bound to the origin so I don't think this will work. See some discussion [here](https://github.com/webrtchacks/adapter/issues/636) in the adapter repository.

Have you tried creating a RTCPeerConnection between content and background script and send the stream that way? Not ideal for a number of reasons but better than nothing.

Comment: +1. I'm trying to avoid the peer connection route for various reasons. I did actually solve this - I'll post up my answer shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: updated. Sadly github doesn't seem to follow the redirect set-up for the repository in general.