# Passing FormData/File Object from content script to background script in chrome extension with Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a chrome extension where I get a file as input from the user and pass it to my background.js (service worker in case of manifest v3) to save it to my backend. Since making cross-origin requests are blocked from content scripts I have to pass the same to my `background.js` and use FETCH API to save the file. When I pass the `FormData` or `File` Object to the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` API it uses JSON Serialization and what I receive in my `background.js` is an empty object. Refer to the below snippet.

```
//content-script.js

attachFile(event) {
 let file = event.target.files[0];

 // file has `File` object uploaded by the user with required contents. 
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'saveAttachment', attachment: file }); 
}
```

```
//background.js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender) => {
 if (request.message === 'saveAttachment') {
   let file = request.attachment; //here the value will be a plain object  {}
 }
});
```

The same happens even when we pass the `FormData` from the content script.

I referred to multiple solutions suggested by the old StackOverflow questions, to use `URL.createObjectURL(myfile);` and pass the URL to my `background.js` and fetch the same file. Whereas FETCH API does not support blob URL to fetch and also `XMLHttpRequest` is not supported in service worker as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193578/pass-input-file-to-background-script). Can someone help me in solving this? Am so blocked with this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently only Firefox can transfer such types directly. Chrome might be able to do it in the [future](https://crbug.com/248548).

#### Workaround 1.

**Serialize the object's contents manually to a string**, send it, possibly in several messages if the length exceeds 64MB message size limit, then rebuild the object in the background script. Below is a simplified example without splitting, adapted from [Violentmonkey](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey/). It's rather slow (encoding and decoding of 50MB takes several seconds) so you may want to write your own version that builds a `multipart/form-data` string in the content script and send it directly in the background script's `fetch`.

- content script:

  ```js
  async function serialize(src) {
    const wasBlob = src instanceof Blob;
    const blob = wasBlob ? src : await new Response(src).blob();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.onload = () => resolve([
        reader.result,
        blob.type,
        wasBlob,
      ]);
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  }
  ```
- background script, inside onMessage listener:

  ```js
  const [body, type] = deserialize(message.body);
  fetch(message.url, {
    body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': type, 
    },
  }).then(/*........*/);
  function deserialize([base64, type, wasBlob]) {
    const str = atob(base64.slice(base64.indexOf(',') + 1));
    const len = str.length;
    const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) arr[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (!wasBlob) {
      type = base64.match(/^data:(.+?);base64/)[1].replace(/(boundary=)[^;]+/,
        (_, p1) => p1 + String.fromCharCode(...arr.slice(2, arr.indexOf(13))));
    }
    return [arr, type];
  }
  ```

#### Workaround 2.

**Use an iframe for an html file in your extension exposed via web_accessible_resources.**
The iframe will be able to do everything an extension can, like making a CORS request.

The File/Blob and [other cloneable types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) can be transferred directly from the content script via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). FormData is not clonable, but you can pass it as `[...obj]` and then assemble in `new FormData()` object.

It can also pass the data directly to the background script via navigator.serviceWorker messaging.

Example: see "**Web messaging (two-way MessagePort)**" in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689866/3959875).

Comment: Thank you so much for this help, Workaround 1 worked very well for me :) I understand the risk at Workaround 2 and am not opting for it.

Comment: @KoushikR could you also use the IndexDB local database proposed by Stainz42 ? Alternatively look into File Access API (will display alert asking for user permission) or File Api?

Comment: @mukunda, well, it works, which means you're wrong (maybe you've copied the code incorrectly or there is another mistake). I've just verified again that a file is transferred successfully.

Comment: thanks for confirming. I already implemented workaround 1, but I want to try workaround 2 again to see what I messed up

Comment: I was trying to pass the data through the "transfer" parameter before. fixed that. now I'm getting a very weird error net::ERR_H2_OR_QUIC_REQUIRED when trying to post the file upload - this is if passing a File. if I try to pass formData in the init section, I get "FormData object could not be cloned."

Comment: and weirdly, I can't reproduce that issue in an isolated test case. this is such a headache lol

Comment: i think there might be a problem when passing from a site's content script to the background iframe. was workaround #2 tested successfully from an extension running on a 3rd party page to pass a File?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it on a live site. As for FormData, indeed it's a bug in all browsers, so you can pass [...formData] via messaging, then assemble it into a new FormData object.

Comment: I only have a problem with passing to service context. It works OK to postMessage without extensions involved. Seems like a chrome bug with drag and drop, and I'm sticking with workaround #1 for now. Fair warning to any brave soul who tries #2 - repro video: https://mukunda.com/2023-01-28%2001-43-10-vc.mp4

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution: you can actually store Blob in the IndexedDB.

```js
// client side (browser action or any page)
import { openDB } from 'idb';

const db = await openDB('upload', 1, {
  upgrade(openedDB) {
    openedDB.createObjectStore('files', {
      keyPath: 'id',
      autoIncrement: true,
    });
  },
});
await db.clear('files');

const fileID = await db.add('files', {
  uploadURL: 'https://yours3bucketendpoint',
  blob: file,
});

navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
  type: 'UPLOAD_MY_FILE_PLEASE',
  payload: { fileID }
});


// Background Service worker
addEventListener('message', async (messageEvent) => {
  if (messageEvent.data?.type === 'UPLOAD_MY_FILE_PLEASE') {
    const db = await openDB('upload', 1);
    const file = await db.get('files', messageEvent.data?.payload?.fileID);
    const blob = file.blob;
    const uploadURL = file.uploadURL;
    
    // it's important here to use self.fetch
    // so the service worker stays alive as long as the request is not finished
    const response = await self.fetch(uploadURL, {
      method: 'put',
      body: blob,
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      // Bravo!
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to pass files from a content page (or from a popup page) to a service worker.
But, probably, it is not suitable for all situations,

You can [intercept a fetch request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent#examples) sent from a content or popup page in a service worker. Then you can send this request through the service-worker, it can also be modified somehow

popup.js:

```
// simple fetch, but with a header indicating that the request should be intercepted
fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Some-Marker': 'true',
    },
});
```

background.js:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    // You can check that the request should be intercepted in other ways, for example, by the request URL
    if (event.request.headers.get('Some-Marker')) {
        event.respondWith((async () => {
            // event.request contains data from the original fetch that was sent from the content or popup page.
            // Here we make a request already in the background.js (service-worker page) and then we send the response to the content page, if it is still active
            // Also here you can modify the request hoy you want
            const result = await self.fetch(event.request);
            return result;
        })());
    }
    return null;
});
```