# Chrome extension page closes when clicking file input button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following use case:

In a chrome extension page (that is, window.html) I need to show a link/button that will allow a user to select one or more files from the local system. These files will then loaded and processed by the plugin.

Approach: Use an `input type=file` to spawn the file open dialog and then handle `change` event of that input.

My problem: 
When I click the button in the popup window, the Open files dialog appears BUT the popup hides away and the javascript code dies. As a workaround, if I right click on the plugin, select "Inspect popup", the popup window no longer closes and the script behind the button runs.

How can I make my javascript run after the user selected the files? (or prevent the popup window closing?)

Code snippets (only relevant lines)

**window.html**

```
 <input id="csv_multiple_load_win" type=file name=files[] multiple />
```

(the `<input>` tag is not included in `form` tag)

**window.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  ....
  $('#csv_multiple_load_win').bind('change', function(event){
  alert("Happy to process the "+event.target.files.length+" files!");
  });
  ....
}
```

What I tried:

*returning false from the event handler

*include the `input` in a form

*putting the loading script in background.js like in [Upload File as a Form Data through chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132971/upload-file-as-a-form-data-through-chrome-extension) question. I tried both approaches. The one in the question and the one in the answer.

*I tried to manually spawn some sort of file dialog (like you would do in a regular code) but I gave up early when I read about some security policies that restricts access to the user file system.

Please help!

**EDIT: The solution**

As @Xan commented, there is no way to prevent the lost focus. When the focus is lost, the window closes and the javascript is killed.
My workaround was to place the code in another pair of html/js files, namely `new_popup.html/js`. The 'new_popup.html' will contain the `<input ...` tag and the 'new_popup.js' the event handling as in previous snippets.

The trick is to spawn a new window that will have this 'new_popup.html' as content. To do this in chrome you have two choices: As a new tab and as a standalone window.

First, you have to create an url to your 'new_popup.html' file which is placed inside the extension:

```
var popup_url = chrome.extension.getURL("new_popup.html");
```

Then, create a new tab in the active window (esp if you want to show more information that maybe will be refreshed):

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url":popup_url}, function(tab){
    alert("Tab with id: "+tab.id+" created!");
});
```

or open a new window (I tried to change the style but they all look the same to me)

```
chrome.windows.create({"url":popup_url, focused:true,type:'panel',
                       width:600, height:250},function(win){
     alert("Popup win created!");
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: You can't prevent the popup from closing on losing focus, so in general file `<input>`s don't work. The question you linked to is the closest to what might work.

Comment: So that we can help you, it's best if you present your attempts in that direction.

Comment: I have two more directions to explore: 1) Open a sort of dashboard in a new tab, where I have my "upload" button, among other info; 2) Use chrome.fileBrowserHandler API. Although I'm not sure about the 2nd approach.

Comment: I can write some tips for 1 as an answer, and 2 is strictly only for ChromeOS

Comment: Heck, some tips - you can open a window with `chrome.windows` with the type popup and optionally stay on top enabled for a dialog-like experience.

Comment: Both approaches work:  Open a new ( tab | window ) with a html+js where you define the multiple file input and the corresponding processing logic. Now it's a design decision :) . p.s. Some code, in few hours/a day