# Chrome extension file upload browse window position off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having an issue with the file browse dialog window appearing off the screen on a Mac when attempting to upload a file within a Google Chrome extension I am developing. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to reposition the dialog window or append the file upload to the main window so it centers with that window? I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132971/upload-file-as-a-form-data-through-chrome-extension) to do my uploads. Any help appreciated! Thank you!

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Bookmark and Binder",
  "description": "example",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "/index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "http://example.com/"
   ]
}
```

A small part of index.html:

```
<div class="form-group chooseFile" id="showUpload" style="display:none">
                    <label>File Upload: </label>
                    <button type="button" id="uploadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Browse and Upload</button>
                </div>
```

On dom ready:

```
$('#uploadButton').on('click', function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'browseAndUpload' });
  });
```

The rest of the script:

```
//background script

/* Creates an `input[type="file]` */
var fileChooser = document.createElement('input');
fileChooser.type = 'file';
fileChooser.multiple = "multiple";

fileChooser.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var files = fileChooser.files;
    var formData = new FormData();
    var inst = $.jstree.reference(newData.reference),
    obj = inst.get_node(newData.reference);
    var uploadURL = apiHost + '/binder/upload?location=' + obj.id;

    formData.append('location', obj.id);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      formData.append('uploads', file, file.name);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', uploadURL, true);

    $('#createModal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      $('body').width('auto');
    })

    xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // File(s) uploaded.
        //uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Upload';
        var inst = $.jstree.reference(newData.reference),
        obj = inst.get_node(newData.reference);

        $('#createModal').modal('hide');
        inst.refresh();
      } else {
        alertEvent("Failure","Please try again later.")
      }
    };

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (evt) {
        console.log('ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState,
                    'Status: ' + xhr.status);
    });

    xhr.send(formData);
    form.reset();   // <-- Resets the input so we do get a `change` event,
                    //     even if the user chooses the same file
});

/* Wrap it in a form for resetting */
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.appendChild(fileChooser);

/* Listen for messages from popup */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.action === 'browseAndUpload') {
        $('body').width('1000px'); //attempt to move the dialog window
        fileChooser.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: The files being uploaded are images?!

Comment: @goitaca It can be any type of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do to make the dialog show in the main window. The user filesystem is sensitive so the browser has several security measures to prevent an scripted upload, that means no dirty tricks here.

So I'd recommend you to pick a different approach to be able to provide a good user experience for uploading a file even from the extension popup.

One possibility is to make use of the `browserAction` popup as a drag and drop zone for your files. It's pretty simple to achieve it, like I demonstrate in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv1nj58p/1/

HTML

```
<div id="file-container">
    <b>DRAG YOUR FILES HERE</b>
    <input id="file" type="file"  multiple="multiple"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#file-container {
    border:2px dashed #aaa;
    background:#eee;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:8px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#file {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    background:magenta;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This fiddle is very raw but if you throw that code in your `index.html` you'll see what I'm suggesting. One downside is, that to properly use the drag drop concept for file input, there is several events that needs to be handled in order to provide visual feedback when one or more files are selected. Fortunately, there are several libraries with that purpose; A good one is is [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

Sadly that's more an alternative than a straight answer. I hope that this solution fits well in your context!

Last but not least, the behavior that you described sounds like a bug to me (probably OS X specific). Feel free to [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) to the chrome team so they can tell you if is that something buggy or ugly, i.e if it's something that they're going to fix or not.

Comment: Good thinking :) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Discovering that the popup for the chrome extension closes out when you try to click in the finder window to browse files :(

Comment: @CaitlinHavener I've tested that before posting the answer just to make sure. However I have only Windows available to my tests :(

Comment: @CaitlinHavener Maybe worth to install some extensions that deals with file upload to see how they solved it. If you find something nice just tell me then I might help you further more, ok?!