# Change Location Of Downloaded HTML Page Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can You Help Me Please Finding Way To Change the Location of a downloaded File by javascript

```
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="page.html">Download</a>
```

this code will download the actual web page in Documents/downloads but i want it to Download it in my desktop !

Comment: browser limitations. You can never access the filesysem from JS to write a file

Comment: As noted above, only the user can choose where to save the file; you do not have control over it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by javascript/jquery. Javascript cannot exert ***any*** control over visitor's file system.

It is a limitation and only user can manually change it from browser.

Following threads can be useful

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988041/how-to-set-the-file-download-location-for-chrome-extension-using-javascript)

[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453798/specify-default-download-folder-possibly-with-javascript)